# How make frameset resize appropriately with jstree context menu

Tags: html, css, jstree, frameset, html4

I'm looking for a solution of how to re-size frames within framesets appropriately (Unfortunately, I'm not given time to convert the legacy app to not use frames). I have a jstree tree view in IE 11 in which the context menu gets cut off because the frame is not re-sized all the way. Please note the following 2 images:

Context menu cut off

[image]

Context menu NOT cut off because frame was manually resized.

[image]

I'm hoping for one of the following possible solutions:

1. What can I add to the frame / css so that the frame automatically resizes when the context menu appears?
2. What can I add to the frame / css so that the context menu will overlap the adjacent frame?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to find a solution that would allow me to dynamically re size the frame when the context menu appears and disappears (Option 2 does not appear to be possible). The following code in my JavaScript allows for the frame to be resided accordingly.

```
// when context menu is shown
$(document).bind('context_show.vakata', function (reference, element, position) {
    $('#adjacentFrame', parent.document).attr('cols', '40%,60%');
});

// when context menu is hidden
$(document).bind('context_hide.vakata', function (reference, element, position) {
    $('#adjacentFrame', parent.document).attr('cols', '30%,70%');
});
```